# Proving a result similar to the diagonal lemma/fixed-point theorem

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, peano-axioms, incompleteness

As the title explains, I'm trying to solve the following exercise that was left for the reader in my lecture notes:

> Show that for any two formulae $F(v_1)$ and $G(v_1)$ in $L_E$ (language of arithmetic with exponentiation) with one free variable, there
> exist sentences $X$ and $Y$ such that the sentences $(X ↔ G(\overline{⌜Y⌝}))$ and $(Y ↔ F(\overline{⌜X⌝}))$ are both true.

(where $⌜X⌝$ means the Gödel number of X, and $\overline{⌜X⌝}$ is the 'logical equivelent' of that Gödel number.)

This clearly resembles the diagonal lemma/fixed-point theorem, except instead of one self-referential sentence we're supposed to have two sentences referring to each other.

I've tried playing around with different combinations of what you might take $X$ and $Y$ to be, attempting to adapt the proof of the diagonal lemma, but haven't had much luck.

Any suggestions anyone could offer would be much appreciated.

[if I've missed out any important details, let me know and I'll add them1]

Comment: Have you tried reducing this to the diagonal lemma by thinking of the desired pair $(X,Y)$ as a fixed point of some operation?

Comment: @Karl sorry, I don't know what operation that would be - the diagonal lemma applies to formulae with one free variable, so I can't work out how you'd apply it to the pair $(X, Y)$?

Comment: Sorry, maybe "reducing" wasn't quite accurate. But roughly, you're looking for a fixed point of the operation $H:(X,Y)\mapsto(G(Y),F(X))$ in the same sense that the diagonal lemma finds a fixed point of $X\mapsto F(X)$.

Comment: I think of the proof of the diagonal lemma as two separate parts: the essential fixed-point trick, which can be seen as an application of the Y combinator from lambda calculus, and the technical part that makes the "types" work out (Godel numbering and the "provable equivalence" indirection).

Comment: So the solution to your exercise ought to work the same way, just with an additional technicality to deal with (i.e. encode) the pair, which we've already figured out how to do as part of the Godel numbering scheme.